# How copy entire directory from one folder to another using laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, copy

May be it's so easy but I couldn't find any proper answer in google or here!!

I did use

```
\File::copyDirectory('public/' . $token . '/cover/', $folderName . '/cover/');
```

but there's no different!!

[This is where I found above solution.](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/148/copying-a-directory-from-one-location-to-another)

Do you know how can I copy entire directory from one folder to another using laravel 5.4?

***Thanks in Advance***

Comment: Try passing an absolute path as opposed to a relative path. perhaps your base directory is not what it seems to be when you execute the code. (I'm saying to prepend a `/` in front of public.

Comment: @Kiyarash can you please aprove my awnser?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

More than one year later :)

Use path helpers functions https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers

```
\File::copyDirectory( public_path . 'to/the/app', resource_path('to/the/app'));
```

Comment: That function is not present on the linked helpers page in 5.6? Even weirder searching "copyDirectory" in laravels entire documentation and there are no results in 8 and 9 either. Does anyone know why the file facade and lots of functions seems to be missing from the documentation entirely? It's very confusing when they are very much present in the source code still.

Answer (score 8):

We can do it in laravel 5.8 using file facade as followings:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;  

File::copyDirectory(__DIR__.'/form-directory', resource_path('to-directory'));
```

Hope, it'll be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
   /* Move test images from public folder to storage folder */
    $source = "source/path";
    $destination = "public/files";

    File::copyDirectory(base_path($source), base_path($destination));
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Storage facades and worked well

*config/filesystems.php*

```
'disks' => [
    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path(),
    ],
     ...
]
```

Copy all files from *public/seed_images/* to *public/images/*

*app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php*

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
$fromFiles = Storage::allFiles('seed_images');
for ($i=0; $i < count($fromFiles) ; $i++) {
    $toFile = str_replace("seed_images","images",$fromFiles[$i]);
    Storage::copy( $fromFiles[$i], $toFile );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * If the destination directory does not actually exist, we will go 
 * ahead and create it recursively, which just gets the destination 
 * prepared to copy the files over. Once we make the directory we'll 
 * proceed the copying.
 *
 * function replaces files with same names
 * 
 * @var bool
 */
$result = File::copyDirectory(
    base_path() . '/storage/source',
    base_path() . '/storage/destination'
);
```

Answer (score -3):

Try using the mix.copy() method.

`mix.copy('public/' . $token . '/cover/', $folderName . '/cover/');`

Read more at: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix#copying-files-and-directories